# Kiviat Diagram with scale always aligned to first axis

Tags: xetex, tkz-kiviat

I'm using Kiviat Diagram to draw graphs, sample code for same is mentioned below:

```
\begin{center}
\psframebox*[fillcolor=white]{
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-5)(5,5)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psKiviat[rotate=0.5,yLabels={Skill3, Skill2, Skill1,Skill9}, labelsep=10pt]{4}{3}
\psKiviatTicklines[Dx=0.5,linecolor=black!30]{4}{3}
\psKiviatAxes[linecolor=black!30]{4}{3}
\psKiviatLine[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=black,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5,fillcolor=green]{\pskillc, \pskillb, \pskilla, \pskillj}
\multido{\rA=0.5+0.5,\iA=20+20}{5}{\uput[3](0,\rA){\iA}}
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{center}
```

Output with three axis:

[image]

Output with Four axis:

[image]

Is there any better way to represent legend scale of `20`,`40`,`60`,`80`,`100`? 
Is it possible to align scale to first axis?

Comment: Please provide a MWE!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a Kiviat diagram? They suggest that their area covered means something, but for 4+ axes the area is dependant on the order in which you put them.

Comment: Is there any good alternative to Kiviat Diagram? Number of axis for me varies from 2 to 10 [in future , it may go upto 20]

Comment: Basically, you want to represent _n_ data points. Sounds like a regular bar plot. This can be done e.g. with _pgfplots_ and the and the `symbolic x coords` option.

Answer (score 1):

While true Kiviat diagrams attribute meaning to the area enclosed, I've seen them used for many numbers of axes. So, appropriateness comments notwithstanding, here are a couple of possible solutions:

### Using `pstricks-add`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-5)(5,5)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psKiviat[rotate=0.5,yLabels={Skill3, Skill2, Skill1,Skill9}, labelsep=10pt]{4}{3}
\psKiviatTicklines[Dx=0.5,linecolor=black!30]{4}{3}
\psKiviatAxes[linecolor=black!30]{4}{3}
\psKiviatLine[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=black,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5,fillcolor=green]{1,0.5,2.5,2.5}
\multido{\rA=0.355+0.355,\iA=20+20}{5}{\uput[-110](\rA,\rA){\iA}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Using `tkz-kiviat`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45]
\tkzKiviatDiagram[
  radial  style/.style={gray!50,-,shorten >=0.5cm},
  radial=4,
  gap=1,
  lattice=5,
  label space=1
]{Skill3,Skill2,Skill1,Skill9}
\tkzKiviatLine[
  thick,
  color=black,
  mark=*,
  mark options={black,thin},
  fill=green!60,
  opacity=.5
](2,1,5,5)
\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=20](0)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]